# Exit views when switching tabs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, uitabbarcontroller

### The Problem

I am trying to use CoreData in my iOS app for persistence. Everything seems to be working well, except for one thing. In some rare cases, I have two view controllers open at the same time that are both accessing the managed object context. The reason for this is that they are both child views of a tab bar controller (and the tab bar controller does not fully exit views when you switch tabs).

### What I'm Looking for

I am looking for a way to make the view exit when I switch to a different tab.

Comment: instead, try to access managed object context from two different threads

Comment: I don't think this would work. This also doesn't seem like the easiest way to solve the problem aswell.

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, there are many things that aren't quite working the way that they are supposed to. Like optionals being nil when they aren't supposed to and entities randomly duplicating. I think it is all tied to the fact that, when I print the managed objects in the context, their data field contains: `<fault>`. That's all I can really figure out.

Comment: its not exactly what you think, have a look at https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-a-core-data-fault--cms-25157

Comment: I think this website has helped me solve half the problem. Take a look at my comment on mgmart's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I've not enough reputation.

If you have to-many relationships it could be an approach to use `.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false` on your fetchrequests.

If your views are doing work while not visible it might be an approach to 
let your views stop any work by instrumenting `viewWillDisappear`. This is just to reduce the energy consumption of your app. IMHO that has nothing to do with your issue accessing faults.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying, but I think you are right. I think the problem was that I was storing the managed objects as an instance variable in one of the views (which is obviously a strong reference), and as such, when switching tabs, the reference was not deallocated.

Comment: I'm not sure that deallocation takes place when switching tabs even as the view still exists although not visible.

Comment: This is what I am saying, I want the instance variable to deallocate. Half of my problems are solved by simply not using an instance variable.

Comment: Are you still getting faults? Have you tried setting `.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false` on the fetchrequest? Maybe this article could be helpful: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/04/24/its-not-your-fault/

Comment: No I have not tried that, but my problems are solved now, I must have been something to do with the references.